# How to reload httpd service on changes automatically using Supervisord?

Tags: centos, centos6, httpd, supervisord, inotify

I am working in a Docker container that so far have the following ready to go:

- CentOS 6 (latest, I think is 6.9)
- Apache 2.2.15 (latest on CentOS6 repositories)
- PHP 5.3.3 (latest on CentOS6 repositories)
- Supervisord 3.3.3

I am stolen the idea from this [nginx.conf](https://github.com/million12/docker-nginx/blob/master/container-files/etc/supervisor.d/nginx.conf) where they are listening using `inotify` for changes (create,delete,modify,move,attrib) at `/etc/nginx/` and `/data/conf/nginx/` and if this happen then Supervisord automatically reload Nginx. This will allow me to forget about be restarting Apache (if it's possible because my experience with Docker is when I bash into the container and execute `service httpd restart` the container exit out) and/or be stopping/building/starting the container each time I want to add a new VH to Apache.

Having said that I am looking for some help with this line:

```
[program:nginx-reload]
command=bash -c 'while inotifywait -q -r -e create,delete,modify,move,attrib --exclude "/\." /etc/nginx/ /data/conf/nginx/; do nginx -t && nginx -s reload; done'
```

Since I am not sure how to write that for achieve the same using `httpd`. Can any give me some help?

Answer (score 0):

Program for supervisord should be like the following:

```
[program:httpd-reload]
command=bash -c 'while inotifywait -q -r -e create,delete,modify,move,attrib --exclude "/\." /etc/httpd/ /data/conf/httpd/; do apachectl -t && service httpd restart; done'
```

Note logs location, you may need exclude it too by adding one more `--exclude "/etc/httpd/logs"` or path where logs are located.

Comment: Cool I'll give a try later today and will let you know